# Receiving "decodeAudioData error null" in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, audio, web

Hello Web Audio Developers,

I am  receiving "decodeAudioData error null" in Chrome 
and 
"decodeAudioData error undefined" in Firebug.

Firebug also says 
"The buffer passed to decodeAudioData contains an unknown content type."

Is there something wrong with this code or 
is there something else that needs to be worked out with the 
"Web Audio API"?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Together 2 </title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = init;
  var context;
  var bufferLoader;
  function init() {
    window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
    context = new AudioContext();
    bufferLoader = new BufferLoader(context,
      [ '../web-audio/path/chrono.mp3' ],
      finishedLoading
    );
    bufferLoader.load();
}

function finishedLoading(bufferList) {
  var source1 = context.createBufferSource();
  source1.buffer = bufferList[0];
  source1.connect(context.destination);
  source1.start(0);
}

function BufferLoader(context, urlList, callback) {
  this.context = context;
  this.urlList = urlList;
  this.onload = callback;
  this.bufferList = new Array();
  this.loadCount = 0;
}
BufferLoader.prototype.loadBuffer = function(url, index) { // Load buffer asynchronously
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open("GET", url, true);
  request.responseType = "arraybuffer";
  var loader = this;
  request.onload = function() {
    // Asynchronously decode the audio file data in request.response
    loader.context.decodeAudioData(
      request.response,
      function(buffer) {
        if (!buffer) {
          alert('error decoding file data: ' + url);
          return;
        }
        loader.bufferList[index] = buffer;
        if (++loader.loadCount == loader.urlList.length)
          loader.onload(loader.bufferList);
      },
      function(error) {
        console.error('decodeAudioData error', error);
      }
    );
  }
  request.onerror = function() {
    alert('BufferLoader: XHR error');
  }
  request.send();
}

BufferLoader.prototype.load = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.urlList.length; ++i)
      this.loadBuffer(this.urlList[i], i);
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was down to the type of codec used on the wav file itself. Only PCM is supported whereas the files that were throwing me errors were MS-ADPCM. You can use QuickTime or VLC to get the codec information and convert them to PCM if necessary.

I'd imagine that it is a similar issue with your MP3.